# AJAX call to vb.net web service returns page HTML instead of calling web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, vb.net, web-services

I have an AJAX call in my WordPress site that needs to call my **vb.net web service**, I have debugged countless times, broken the code to try get a different result but I always get the same thing: it just returns my page html no matter what I try. I have confirmed that My site has the latest version of jQuery installed and I have confirmed its not a CORS problem.

This is displayed after ajax call runs:

[image: Success message]

Ajax call:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#Mybtn").click(function () {
        try {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://test.labourlog.com/wsmain.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    type: 'post',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Success" + msg);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Ajax call Failed" + errorThrown);
                    }
                });           
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Call Api Failed" + e);
        }
    });
});
```

I have search several forums and articles but I can find a solution to this problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: What web method do you want to trigger, and what are the conditions on which it needs to be triggered?

Comment: **Public Sub PurchaseDataTransporter()** at the moment it launches as soon as the website starts for testing purposes

Comment: @31piy ,  
It does not take any parameters, and does not return anything to the website I simply just need it to run, basically what my web method does is fetch data from one database and send it to another –

Comment: I have tried different methods no matter what i do it returns the body html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I found a fix, 
one of the problems was a CORS error which i fixed by moving everything to the same domain.

But still returned the body html Fixed this by adding the following protocols to the **web.config** file on the server under **system.web**

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```